# Finding minimum of a function in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the minimum of the following  function $\frac{1}{2} \left(-\alpha ^2 \sin (\theta )-\alpha ^2 \cos (\theta )-\alpha ^2 \sin (\theta ) \tan (\theta )+\frac{4 \alpha ^3 \sin ^3(\theta ) \csc (2 \theta ) \left(2 \alpha ^9+\alpha ^8 (2 \beta
   -11)+\alpha ^7 (24-10 \beta )+\alpha ^6 \left(-4 \beta ^3+9 \beta ^2+11 \beta -22\right)+\alpha ^5 \left(9 \beta ^4+8 \beta ^3-51 \beta ^2+34 \beta -8\right)+\alpha ^4 \left(13 \beta ^5-28 \beta ^4-38
   \beta ^3+146 \beta ^2-133 \beta +48\right)-2 \alpha ^3 (\beta -1)^2 \left(7 \beta ^3+17 \beta ^2-41 \beta +32\right)+\alpha ^2 (\beta -1)^3 \left(\beta ^3-12 \beta ^2+45 \beta -46\right)+\alpha 
   (\beta -1) \left(\alpha ^6+\alpha ^5 \left(-9 \beta ^2+9 \beta -6\right)+\alpha ^4 \left(-13 \beta ^3+41 \beta ^2-37 \beta +15\right)+\alpha ^3 \left(-4 \beta ^4+36 \beta ^3-74 \beta ^2+62 \beta
   -20\right)+3 \alpha ^2 (\beta -1)^3 (3 \beta -5)-\alpha  (\beta -1)^4 \left(\beta ^2-\beta +6\right)-(\beta -1)^5 \left(\beta ^2+1\right)\right) \tan (\theta )+\alpha  (\beta -1)^4 \left(3 \beta ^4-4
   \beta ^3-3 \beta ^2+14 \beta -18\right)+(\beta -1)^6 \left(3 \beta ^3+\beta ^2+\beta +3\right)\right)}{\alpha ^{10}-10 \alpha ^9+9 \alpha ^8 \left(\beta ^2-2 \beta +5\right)+8 \alpha ^7 \left(\beta
   ^3-9 \beta ^2+15 \beta -15\right)+2 \alpha ^6 \left(5 \beta ^4-36 \beta ^3+132 \beta ^2-176 \beta +105\right)-12 \alpha ^5 \left(5 \beta ^4-22 \beta ^3+48 \beta ^2-50 \beta +21\right)+2 \alpha ^4
   (\beta -1)^2 \left(5 \beta ^4-20 \beta ^3+72 \beta ^2-120 \beta +105\right)+8 \alpha ^3 (\beta -1)^3 \left(\beta ^4-6 \beta ^3+12 \beta ^2-16 \beta +15\right)+3 \alpha ^2 (\beta -1)^4 \left(3 \beta
   ^4-12 \beta ^3+22 \beta ^2-20 \beta +15\right)-2 \alpha  (\beta -1)^6 \left(9 \beta ^2-6 \beta +5\right)+(\beta -1)^{10}}-2 \alpha  \beta  \sin (\theta )+2 \alpha  (\alpha +\beta +1) \sin (\theta )+2
   \alpha  \sin (\theta ) (\alpha  \tan (\theta )-\beta )-2 (\beta -1) (\beta  \cos (\theta )-\alpha  \sin (\theta ))+(\alpha -1)^2 \cos (\theta )+2 \alpha  \cos (\theta )-\beta ^2 \sin (\theta )+2 \beta
   ^2 \cos (\theta )+(\beta -1)^2 \sin (\theta )+2 \beta  \sin (\theta )-2 \beta  \cos (\theta )-\sin (\theta )-\cos (\theta )\right)$

When $\beta,\alpha\in [1/2,1]$, $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$ and $\theta <\arctan[\frac{\beta}{\alpha}]$. Now I am not able to do this by hand myself given that the function is very complicated but I used the command FindMinimum and Mathematica did return a value and said that the value at this minimum is bigger than $0$, wich was what I wanted to see. Now I assume that this is done using some numerical methods that I am not familiar with and we have some error factors. Now my questions is does anyone know what this method is and what is the value of the error associated to him ? Thanks in advance .

This is the code for the expression :

```
1/2 (-Cos[θ] + (-1 + α)^2 Cos[θ] + 
   2 α Cos[θ] - α^2 Cos[θ] - 
   2 β Cos[θ] + 2 β^2 Cos[θ] - 
   Sin[θ] - α^2 Sin[θ] + (-1 + β)^2 Sin[\
θ] + 2 β Sin[θ] - 
   2 α β Sin[θ] - β^2 Sin[θ] + 
   2 α (1 + α + β) Sin[θ] - 
   2 (-1 + β) (β Cos[θ] - α Sin[θ]) \
- α^2 Sin[θ] Tan[θ] + 
   2 α Sin[θ] (-β + α Tan[θ]) + (4 \
α^3 Csc[
       2 θ] Sin[θ]^3 (2 α^9 + α^7 (24 - 
           10 β) + α^8 (-11 + 
           2 β) + α^6 (-22 + 11 β + 9 β^2 - 
           4 β^3) + α^2 (-1 + β)^3 (-46 + 
           45 β - 
           12 β^2 + β^3) + (-1 + β)^6 (3 + β \
+ β^2 + 3 β^3) - 
        2 α^3 (-1 + β)^2 (32 - 41 β + 
           17 β^2 + 
           7 β^3) + α (-1 + β)^4 (-18 + 
           14 β - 3 β^2 - 4 β^3 + 
           3 β^4) + α^5 (-8 + 34 β - 
           51 β^2 + 8 β^3 + 
           9 β^4) + α^4 (48 - 133 β + 
           146 β^2 - 38 β^3 - 28 β^4 + 
           13 β^5) + α (-1 + β) (α^6 + 
           3 α^2 (-1 + β)^3 (-5 + 
              3 β) + α^5 (-6 + 9 β - 
              9 β^2) - (-1 + β)^5 (1 + β^2) - \
α (-1 + β)^4 (6 - β + β^2) + α^4 (15 \
- 37 β + 41 β^2 - 13 β^3) + α^3 (-20 + 
              62 β - 74 β^2 + 36 β^3 - 
              4 β^4)) Tan[θ]))/(-10 α^9 + \
α^10 + (-1 + β)^10 + 
      9 α^8 (5 - 2 β + β^2) - 
      2 α (-1 + β)^6 (5 - 6 β + 9 β^2) + 
      8 α^7 (-15 + 15 β - 9 β^2 + β^3) + 
      8 α^3 (-1 + β)^3 (15 - 16 β + 12 β^2 - 
         6 β^3 + β^4) + 
      3 α^2 (-1 + β)^4 (15 - 20 β + 22 β^2 - 
         12 β^3 + 3 β^4) + 
      2 α^6 (105 - 176 β + 132 β^2 - 
         36 β^3 + 5 β^4) - 
      12 α^5 (21 - 50 β + 48 β^2 - 22 β^3 + 
         5 β^4) + 
      2 α^4 (-1 + β)^2 (105 - 120 β + 
         72 β^2 - 20 β^3 + 5 β^4)))
```

Comment: For global optimization with `NMinimize` see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html . For local optimization with `FindMinimum`, see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html . If you want any help with finding the minimum of that huge expression, then you need to copy the code in, because it's far too long to type out.

Comment: `FindMinimum[{expr, 0 < \[Theta] < ArcTan[\[Beta]/\[Alpha]], 
  1/2 <= \[Alpha] <= 1, 
  1/2 <= \[Beta] <= 1}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta]}]` returns an error of `9.36515*10^-8`, while `NMinimize` returns an error of `4.52727*10^-10`. Using `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"`, then `NMinimize` returns and even lower error of `2.33019*10^-11` with result: `{\[Alpha] -> 0.5, \[Beta] -> 0.635514, \[Theta] -> 1.86415*10^-10}`. It looks like there are minima for alpha 1/2, beta is anything, and as theta approaches k*pi for integer k.

Comment: ^ set both a/b to half and try: `With[{a = 1/2, b = 1/2},
 Plot[(expr /. {\[Alpha] -> a, \[Beta] -> b}), {\[Theta], -10, 
   ArcTan[b/a]}]
 ]` you'll see that clearly theta must be approach zero and indeed `Limit[expr, \[Theta] -> 0]` is zero.