# Finding the minimum of a complicated Function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the minimum of the following function

```
1/2 (2 r - 2 r \[Alpha] - 2 r \[Beta] + 2 r (1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta]) -
    Cos[\[Theta]] + (-1 + \[Alpha])^2 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
   2 \[Alpha] Cos[\[Theta]] - \[Alpha]^2 Cos[\[Theta]] - 
   2 \[Beta] Cos[\[Theta]] + 2 \[Beta]^2 Cos[\[Theta]] - 
   2 (-1 + \[Beta]) (-r + \[Beta] Cos[\[Theta]]) - 
   r^2 Csc[\[Theta]] + 2 r (-\[Alpha] + r Csc[\[Theta]]) - 
   r^2 Sec[\[Theta]] + 
   2 r (-\[Beta] + 
      r Sec[\[Theta]]) + (4 r^3 Csc[
       2 \[Theta]] (3 - 17 \[Alpha] + 40 \[Alpha]^2 - 48 \[Alpha]^3 + 
        22 \[Alpha]^4 + 22 \[Alpha]^5 - 48 \[Alpha]^6 + 
        40 \[Alpha]^7 - 17 \[Alpha]^8 + 3 \[Alpha]^9 - 17 \[Beta] + 
        80 \[Alpha] \[Beta] - 152 \[Alpha]^2 \[Beta] + 
        144 \[Alpha]^3 \[Beta] - 58 \[Alpha]^4 \[Beta] - 
        16 \[Alpha]^5 \[Beta] + 32 \[Alpha]^6 \[Beta] - 
        16 \[Alpha]^7 \[Beta] + 3 \[Alpha]^8 \[Beta] + 40 \[Beta]^2 - 
        152 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^2 + 216 \[Alpha]^2 \[Beta]^2 - 
        136 \[Alpha]^3 \[Beta]^2 + 32 \[Alpha]^4 \[Beta]^2 - 
        48 \[Beta]^3 + 144 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^3 - 
        136 \[Alpha]^2 \[Beta]^3 + 72 \[Alpha]^4 \[Beta]^3 - 
        32 \[Alpha]^5 \[Beta]^3 + 22 \[Beta]^4 - 
        58 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^4 + 32 \[Alpha]^2 \[Beta]^4 + 
        72 \[Alpha]^3 \[Beta]^4 - 82 \[Alpha]^4 \[Beta]^4 + 
        22 \[Alpha]^5 \[Beta]^4 + 22 \[Beta]^5 - 
        16 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^5 - 32 \[Alpha]^3 \[Beta]^5 + 
        22 \[Alpha]^4 \[Beta]^5 - 48 \[Beta]^6 + 
        32 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^6 + 40 \[Beta]^7 - 
        16 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^7 - 17 \[Beta]^8 + 3 \[Alpha] \[Beta]^8 + 
        3 \[Beta]^9 - 
        r (-1 + \[Alpha]) (\[Alpha]^7 + \[Alpha]^5 (11 - 
              5 \[Beta]) + \[Alpha]^6 (-5 + \[Beta]) - (-1 + \
\[Beta])^6 - \[Alpha] (-1 + \[Beta])^3 (5 - 10 \[Beta] + 
              9 \[Beta]^2) + \[Alpha]^4 (-15 + 16 \[Beta] - 
              9 \[Beta]^2 + 
              4 \[Beta]^3) + \[Alpha]^2 (-1 + \[Beta])^2 (-11 + 
              19 \[Beta] - 23 \[Beta]^2 + 
              9 \[Beta]^3) + \[Alpha]^3 (15 - 34 \[Beta] + 
              42 \[Beta]^2 - 36 \[Beta]^3 + 
              13 \[Beta]^4)) Csc[\[Theta]] - 
        r (-1 + \[Beta]) (-\[Alpha]^6 - 
           3 \[Alpha]^2 (-1 + \[Beta])^3 (-5 + 
              
              3 \[Beta]) + (-1 + \[Beta])^5 (1 + \[Beta]^2) + \
\[Alpha] (-1 + \[Beta])^4 (6 - \[Beta] + \[Beta]^2) + \[Alpha]^5 (6 - 
              9 \[Beta] + 9 \[Beta]^2) + \[Alpha]^4 (-15 + 
              37 \[Beta] - 41 \[Beta]^2 + 
              13 \[Beta]^3) + \[Alpha]^3 (20 - 62 \[Beta] + 
              74 \[Beta]^2 - 36 \[Beta]^3 + 
              4 \[Beta]^4)) Sec[\[Theta]]))/(-10 \[Alpha]^9 + \
\[Alpha]^10 + (-1 + \[Beta])^10 + 
      9 \[Alpha]^8 (5 - 2 \[Beta] + \[Beta]^2) - 
      2 \[Alpha] (-1 + \[Beta])^6 (5 - 6 \[Beta] + 9 \[Beta]^2) + 
      8 \[Alpha]^7 (-15 + 15 \[Beta] - 9 \[Beta]^2 + \[Beta]^3) + 
      8 \[Alpha]^3 (-1 + \[Beta])^3 (15 - 16 \[Beta] + 12 \[Beta]^2 - 
         6 \[Beta]^3 + \[Beta]^4) + 
      3 \[Alpha]^2 (-1 + \[Beta])^4 (15 - 20 \[Beta] + 22 \[Beta]^2 - 
         12 \[Beta]^3 + 3 \[Beta]^4) + 
      2 \[Alpha]^6 (105 - 176 \[Beta] + 132 \[Beta]^2 - 
         36 \[Beta]^3 + 5 \[Beta]^4) - 
      12 \[Alpha]^5 (21 - 50 \[Beta] + 48 \[Beta]^2 - 22 \[Beta]^3 + 
         5 \[Beta]^4) + 
      2 \[Alpha]^4 (-1 + \[Beta])^2 (105 - 120 \[Beta] + 
         72 \[Beta]^2 - 20 \[Beta]^3 + 5 \[Beta]^4)) - 
   Sin[\[Theta]] - 2 \[Alpha] Sin[\[Theta]] + 
   2 \[Alpha]^2 Sin[\[Theta]] + (-1 + \[Beta])^2 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
   2 \[Beta] Sin[\[Theta]] - \[Beta]^2 Sin[\[Theta]] - 
   2 (-1 + \[Alpha]) (-r + \[Alpha] Sin[\[Theta]]))
```

When I have the following conditions $\beta \in [1/2,1], \alpha\in [1/2,1], 0\leq\theta leq ArcTan[\beta/\alpha]$ and $r\in [0,\alpha\sin(\theta)]$. Now for this I use NMinimize and it return a point where I have a value that is of the form $-1.40513*10^{-16}$. Now since I need to check if this function takes a negative value or not precision here is important so how can I be sure that considering the error term this will in fact not be positive. Also I have tried doing the $3D-$Plot of this function , When I substitued $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and made vary $r,\theta$ and this plot gives me a function that is $\geq 0$. I don't know how to check if this will in fact be negative or not, any help is aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the same function as in your previous question - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228239/finding-minimum-of-a-function-in-mathematica - ?

Comment: Not this is a more general case , here we have an extra variable. @HighPerformanceMark